# Convert webapp w/ Yii to native app - Apache Cordova & Netbeans

Tags: php, cordova, netbeans, yii, nativeapplication

I have a question about web and native app development and integrating multiple frameworks.

I currently have a web app (html 5, css, js/jquery, php, mysql) and want to make available as a native app on Android and iOS. It uses [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com) framework and I was thinking about using Netbeans IDE and [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org) to make the conversion. How do I go about this? Can someone supply some links or an explanation to clear things up for me?

If you have a different method you'd like to recommend instead of Cordova, I'd appreciate that too. Please provide why you prefer that method though.

I've seen plenty of information on this forum and the web that explains this process, but non with Yii in mind.

Thank you for all and any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. since we have decided to drop the native app and use an html5 website design i picked, Yii+backbone.js .

in your case, if you plan on building a native app, the backend ( PHP or Yii in your case ) will not be used as a smart web server , because you will use a JS framework.

Known and well loved and used frameworks are:

- angular.js
- backbone.js
- knockout.js
- ember.js

Comment: Thanks for the comment it was very helpful, cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, php is a server side language. Its not client based. Yii could serve as a backend providing the data thats all. When you want to use cordova you need a client side framework like jquery mobile.